Validator, only English letters and punctuation in a request using golang
I'm building my first web service using Golang.
I want a validator which check that an attribute has only English letters and punctuation marks.
I found out that validation "github.com/astaxie/beego/validation" package is very simple and convinient, and I decided to use Match validator with the following regexp as follows:
type ParagraphRequest struct {
// Regular expression to match only English letters, punctuation, and spaces
Paragraph string `json:"paragraph" valid:"Required;Match(/^[a-zA-Z\s.,!?;:'\"()\-]+$/);MaxSize(1000)"`
}

But for some reason when I send a request with letters from another languages, the check ignores it and doesn't raise any error:
// BindAndValid binds and validates data
func BindAndValid(c *gin.Context, request interface{}) int {
    err := c.Bind(request)
    if err != nil {
        return http.StatusBadRequest
    }

valid := validation.Validation{}
check, err := valid.Valid(request)
if err != nil {
    return http.StatusInternalServerError
}
if !check {
    MarkErrors(valid.Errors)
    return http.StatusBadRequest
}

return http.StatusOK
}

What am I missing? I checked the regexp, using regexp.MustCompile, and it works fine.
I'm open to alternatives (other than beego).
Edit:
The json request
{
    "paragraph": "Hi, My name is Kali!"
}


I'm not an expert on GO, but one thing I would look at would be the request json format and whether the validation expression is right. It looks (again, not expert), it is expecting a json and an attribute on it to have the name "paragraph" so what is the request format ?

Exactly, a json with an attribute name "paragraph"

Trying to assume certain characters are not “English” might be naïve, but I will enjoy my frappé while you pull something out of the æther

Can you add to your question the Json for the request please?

@JorgeCampos added the request :)

@JimB, æther seems to be a bit of stretch for "English", https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=%C3%A6ther&hl=en.

@ZachYoung, yeah, just the first things that came to mind, but the point was that “English” is not limited to ascii especially when already dealing with utf8

If you already checked regexp.MustCompile and it worked, why not go with that? It doesn't seem like much code to write:
var rePara = regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-zA-Z\s.,!?;:'\"()\-]+$`)

func validatePara(s string) bool {
    return len(s) <= 1000 && rePara.MatchString(s)
}

func Test_validatePara(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tc := range []struct {
        s    string
        want bool
    }{
        {"foo", true},
        {"föo", false},
        {"foo?", true},
        {"¿foo?", false},
        {strings.Repeat("foo", 333) + ".", true},
        {strings.Repeat("foo", 333) + "??", false},
    } {
        if got := validatePara(tc.s); got != tc.want {
            s := tc.s
            if len(s) > 10 {
                s = fmt.Sprintf("%s...(len=%d)", s[:10], len(s))
            }
            t.Errorf("Validate(%s)=%t; want %t", s, got, tc.want)
        }
    }
}


If you want to allow only unicode in your regex, you need to use these:

\p{L}: Matches any Unicode letter, which includes non-English characters.
\p{N}: Matches any Unicode number (digits).
\p{P}: Matches punctuation marks.
\p{Z}: Matches spaces and other separators.

I think you need to change your regex to:
/^[\p{L}\s.,!?;:'"()\u002D]+$/

Here \u002D is unicode hiphen

But I want English letters only.

Hi, . OP asked for English letters and punctuation only, and already provided a regexp that works for them. Your solution clearly states it will allow non-English characters.
